# Normalize different date data into single format in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am currently analyzing a dateset which contains so many different date types like

```
12/31/1991
December 10, 1980
September 25, 1970
2005-11-14
December 1990
October 12, 2005
1993-06-26
```

Is there a way to normalize all the date data into single format 'YYYY-MM-DD' ? I am familiar with datetime package in Python, but what's the best way to approach this problem so that it can handle all the different date types.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are okay with using a library, you can use the [`dateutil` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) function, and parse all the dates into datetime objects, and then use [`datetime.datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to parse them back into strings in the format you want.

Install `dateutil`:

```sh
pip3 install python-dateutil
```

Example:

```py
s = ["12/31/1991",
"December 10, 1980",
"September 25, 1970",
"2005-11-14",
"December 1990",
"October 12, 2005",
"1993-06-26",
"11/20/1967 6:08:15 PM"]

from dateutil import parser
for i in s:
    d = parser.parse(i)
    print(d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Output:

```
1991-12-31 00:00:00 
1980-12-10 00:00:00 
1970-09-25 00:00:00 
2005-11-14 00:00:00 
1990-12-05 00:00:00 
2005-10-12 00:00:00 
1993-06-26 00:00:00 
1967-11-20 18:08:15
```

A thing to note, `dateutil.parser.parse` would use the current datetime to make up for any parts of the datetime if they are missing in the string (as can be seen above in the parsing of `'December 1990'` , which got parsed as - `1990-12-10` as `10` is the current date).

If a time is not supplied then `00:00:00` is used. See the [documentation](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) for how to handle time zones.

Comment: `December 1990` is actually invalid but still it is showing  `1990-12-10`. Is there a way to flag?

Comment: Let me check if there is anything that can be done about that.

Comment: Using regular expression, I have resolved the issue. Thanks

Comment: Answer accepted. Thank you :)

Comment: make sure you are definitely feeding in datetimes as `parse` will give unexpected results: `parse('of 5')==datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 5, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this issue:

```
from  dateutil.parser import parse
dt = parse(str(row))
print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

It is able to handle different date types.