# Python Nomarlizing Date Giving a Format

Tags: python, date

So if several date strings with different formats and am looking for a way to normalize dates given the format.

For example, if I have three sets of date strings and their associated format strings:

`date = 11/20/2020`, `format = MM/DD/YYYY`

`date = 11-20-2020`, `format = MM-DD-YYYY`

`date = 20-11-2020`, `format = DD-MM-YYYY`

I am looking to normalize all of these dates into the format of `YYYY-MM`. Is there a way I can normalize the `date` if I am giving the `format`? Can the `datetime` package help here?

Nice to have: If there is a way to take in other types of dates too (ex: UTC format), that would be helpful as well

What I have so far is this:

```
date_list = re.split(r'\W+', date)
date_format_list = re.split(r'\W+', format)

year_index = date_format_list.index('YYYY')
month_index = date_format_list.index('MM')

formatted_year = date_list[year_index]
formatted_month = date_list[month_index]

'-'.join([formatted_year, formatted_month])
```

**Update** I am not able to change the `format` string which is causing the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normalize different date data into single format in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051147/normalize-different-date-data-into-single-format-in-python)

Comment: If the answer solves your issue don't forget to accept that answer and close the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strptime` method in the `datetime` package can be used. You have to give the date as a string in the first parameter followed by the format of the date.

```py
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime('11/20/2020', '%m/%d/%Y')
print(str_time)
```

You also have the `strftime` method which will compare a date object with the format and do the same.

```
date = datetime.strftime(date_obj, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

You can find the difference between them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `datetime` package contains what you need.
You'll need to review the package docs and create a format string that matches each of your formats, but this is the idea

```
from datetime import datetime
date_str = '11/20/2020'
format_str = '%m/%d/%Y'
date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%Y')
date.isoformat()
```